# ¿Cómo pasar el valor del atributo "id" al atributo "name" pero a muchos inputs desde jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5

mi problema es el siguiente;

Tengo un formulario con 10 inputs y todos tienen su respectiva clase y también su id, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es agregarles el atributo name que tenga el mismo valor que el id y para ello estoy utilizando jquery, ejemplo:

```
{#formulario.html#}
    <form action="">
        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" id="id01" class="inputs_names">
            <input type="text" id="id02" class="inputs_names">
            <input type="text" id="id03" class="inputs_names">
            <input type="text" id="id04" class="inputs_names">
            <input type="text" id="id05" class="inputs_names">
            <input type="text" id="id06" class="inputs_names">
            <input type="text" id="id07" class="inputs_names">
            <input type="text" id="id08" class="inputs_names">
            <input type="text" id="id09" class="inputs_names">
            <input type="text" id="id10" class="inputs_names">
        </div>
    </form>
```

El problema está en que cuando hago esto, si me agrega el atributo "name" pero con el último elemento de la lista en los 10 inputs:

```
// logica.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let list_ids = []

    $('.inputs_names').each(function () {
        list_ids.push($(this).attr('id'))
    })

    for (let i = 0; i < list_ids.length; i++) {
        console.log(list_ids[i])
        $('.inputs_names').attr('name', list_ids[i])
    }


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazlo así:

```
$('.inputs_names').each(function () {
  $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('id'))
})
```

Con eso te evitas tener que guardar y recorrer ese array list_ids.

Tu error es que en esta instrucción:

```
$('.inputs_names').attr('name', list_ids[i])
```

estás sobreescribiendo todos a la vez en cada ciclo, y se queda con el valor del útimo ciclo.

Si realmente quieres seguir usándolo de esa forma debes hacerlo así:

```
$('.inputs_names:eq('+i+')').attr('name', list_ids[i])
```

Es decir, usando el selector [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) de jquery, que selecciona el elemento en la posición de índice seleccionada dentro del conjunto de elementos seleccionados.